# 4 nested IF conditions in Excel not accepted "you've entered too many arguments for this function"

Tags: excel, if-statement

Excel: I have 3 if conditions that I want to apply in order (if else if else if)

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<4;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+4;"NOT_TRUE";)

=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<7;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+7;"NOT_TRUE";)

=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<9;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+9;"NOT_TRUE";)
```

I put them together (nested) (Inside each other) Like this

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<4;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+4;"NOT_TRUE";IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<7;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+7;"NOT_TRUE";IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1))<9;A9>30);INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9);"0");1)+9;"NOT_TRUE";)))
```

Now Excel gives me an error message saying "you've entered too many arguments for this function"

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. Perhaps you have a bracket in the wrong place?

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A12),"0"),1))<4,A12>30),INT(A12)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A12),"0"),1)+4,IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9),"0"),1))<7,A9>30),INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9),"0"),1)+7,IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9),"0"),1))<9,A9>30),INT(A9)-RIGHT(TEXT(INT(A9),"0"),1)+9,"NOT_TRUE")))
```

Comment: You're using commas where OP is using semicolons as well.

Comment: It is worth remembering that commas or semi-colons are dependant on the region settings of each persons computer....  So you have to adjust for that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, just had to replace commas with semicolons